# Select all rows that do NOT match in MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I would like to get as result all rows from the table except the rows inside the query. **Update: The rows need to be added or removed from the result set on basis of the three properties makeModelDescription, firstRegistration and mileage. Only if all three values match the row should not be part of the result set. The WHERE clause will contain up to 20 conditions.** Therefore I tried

```
SELECT * 
FROM cars 
WHERE (makeModelDescription<>'Seat Arosa 2.0 Stella' AND 
       firstRegistration='EZ 03/2005' AND mileage='101.000 km') OR 
      (makeModelDescription<>'Seat Arosa 3.0 Stella' AND 
       firstRegistration='EZ 03/2005' AND mileage='101.000 km')
```

with a sample table:

[image]

But instead of getting the expected result:

- BMW X5 4.4 i aus erster Hand
- Corvette C5 Cabrio Seat
- Arosa 4.0 Stella

I got the result:

[image]

Can anybody with more experience please support and help to formulate the correct query.

Comment: @all: I realized that I did not formulate the question properly. Therefore I opened a new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31873585/select-all-rows-minus-rows-from-where-clause and requested from stackoverflow to delete this question.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you are doing this with your `SELECT` :

```
SELECT * 
FROM cars 
WHERE firstRegistration='EZ 03/2005' AND mileage='101.000 km'
```

since you put a `OR` between both models.

So, you just need to look if they are different than the models that you are refering to :

```
SELECT * 
FROM cars 
WHERE (makeModelDescription <>'Seat Arosa 2.0 Stella' AND 
       makeModelDescription <>'Seat Arosa 3.0 Stella')
```

**EDITED :**

```
SELECT * 
FROM cars 
WHERE (makeModelDescription <>'Seat Arosa 2.0 Stella' AND 
       makeModelDescription <>'Seat Arosa 3.0 Stella')  OR 
        firstRegistration <>'EZ 03/2005' OR
        mileage<>'101.000 km'
```

Comment: Or change the `OR` by an `AND`

Comment: @nada This will not work...Corvette and BMW are not `firstRegistration='EZ 03/2005' AND mileage='101.000 km'`

Comment: @FabienTheSolution: Thanks for the fast response! But what if I have two Seat Arosa 2.0 Stella, one with e. g. firstRegistration 'EZ 03/2005' and the other one with EZ 03/2006 km. How would I need to formulate the query to exclude only the first Seat Arosa 2.0 Stella?

Comment: See the edited answer. You take it if it's different than `Seat Arosa 2.0 Stella` or if it's different than `EZ 03/2005`...So if it's `EZ 03/2006`, the `SELECT`statement with take this entry

Comment: @FabienTheSolution: Hi, just followed your instructions but I still get sometimes a wrong result set. I also realized that I did not make a really good description of the requirement. Therefore I updated the description. Main challenge is the selection of multiple rows based on the three properties mentioned in the description. Many thanks in advance. By the way... maybe there is another, smarter way to do the SQL query.

Comment: I edited the answer again...This one will take any cars that is not `Seat Arosa 2.0 Stella` or `Seat Arosa 3.0 Stella`. It will also take cars that are `Seat Arosa 2.0 Stella` or `Seat Arosa 3.0 Stella` only if they have `firstRegistration` different than `EZ 03/2005` and `mileage` different than `101.000 km`

Answer (score 0):

Your WHERE condition is logically wrong,

```
(
    makeModelDescription<>'Seat Arosa 2.0 Stella' 
    AND firstRegistration='EZ 03/2005' 
    AND mileage='101.000 km'
)

    OR 

(
    makeModelDescription<>'Seat Arosa 3.0 Stella' 
    AND firstRegistration='EZ 03/2005' 
    AND mileage='101.000 km'
)
```

Here what happens now is, both conditions becomes true when the `firstRegistration` becomes equal to `EZ 03/2005` (and also if `mileage` becomes equal to `101.000km`). What you should do is only omit the records where `makeModelDescription` is equal to `Seat Arosa 2.0 Stella` `OR` `Seat Arosa 3.0 Stella`. So your query should be like below,

```
SELECT * 
FROM cars 
WHERE 
makeModelDescription <>'Seat Arosa 2.0 Stella'
AND 
makeModelDescription <>'Seat Arosa 3.0 Stella'
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! But what if I have two Seat Arosa 2.0 Stella, one with e. g. firstRegistration 'EZ 03/2005' and the other one with EZ 03/2006 km. How would I need to formulate the query to exclude only the first Seat Arosa 2.0 Stella?