# SELECT all rows MINUS rows from WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

How would I need to modify the query so that I get as result all rows from the table except the once I used in the query?

```
SELECT * 
FROM cars 
WHERE (makeModelDescription='Seat Arosa 2.0 Stella' 
         AND firstRegistration='EZ 03/2005' 
         AND mileage='101.000 km') 
      OR (makeModelDescription='Seat Arosa 3.0 Stella' 
             AND firstRegistration='EZ 03/2005' 
             AND mileage='101.000 km')
```

Kindly note that it's important to use all three properties makeModelDescription, firstRegistration and mileage as key in the condition.

Reference table:

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

--
-- Datenbank: `ref-table`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Tabellenstruktur für Tabelle `cars`
--

CREATE TABLE `cars` (
  `makeModelDescription` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `firstRegistration` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `mileage` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `createTime` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `updateTime` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Daten für Tabelle `cars`
--

INSERT INTO `cars` (`makeModelDescription`, `firstRegistration`, `mileage`, `status`, `createTime`, `updateTime`) VALUES
('BMW X5 4.4 i  aus erster Hand', 'EZ 07/2000', '226.000 km', 'active', 1438870958, 1438870958),
('Corvette C5 Cabrio', 'EZ 03/2001', '96.000 km', 'active', 1438870958, 1438870958),
('Seat Arosa 2.0 Stella', 'EZ 03/2005', '101.000 km', 'active', 1436891529, 1436891529),
('Seat Arosa 2.0 Stella', 'EZ 03/2006', '101.000 km', 'active', 1436891529, 1436891529),
('Seat Arosa 3.0 Stella', 'EZ 03/2005', '101.000 km', 'active', 1437029730, 1437029730),
('Seat Arosa 4.0 Stella', 'EZ 03/2005', '101.000 km', 'active', 1437112074, 1437112074);

--
-- Indizes der exportierten Tabellen
--

--
-- Indizes für die Tabelle `cars`
--
ALTER TABLE `cars`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`makeModelDescription`,`firstRegistration`,`mileage`);
```

It used to be an easy task to get the query by myself, but actually its not that trivial. I also tried already different proposed solutions, but unit now none of them delivered the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As all columns are not nullable, you can simply use NOT to get those records that don't match the conditions:

```
SELECT * 
FROM cars 
WHERE NOT
(
  (makeModelDescription='Seat Arosa 2.0 Stella' 
   AND firstRegistration='EZ 03/2005' 
   AND mileage='101.000 km') 
  OR 
  (makeModelDescription='Seat Arosa 3.0 Stella' 
   AND firstRegistration='EZ 03/2005' 
   AND mileage='101.000 km')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1765e/1/0

```
SELECT * 
FROM cars 
WHERE NOT ((makeModelDescription='Seat Arosa 2.0 Stella' 
         AND firstRegistration='EZ 03/2005' 
         AND mileage='101.000 km') 
      OR (makeModelDescription='Seat Arosa 3.0 Stella' 
             AND firstRegistration='EZ 03/2005' 
             AND mileage='101.000 km'))
```